# how can i debug with intelij tomcat by using gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

i have found this [tutorial](https://stefancosma.xyz/2018/10/01/how-to-use-tomcat-intellij-idea-community/)
it tell how to make it with maven, but instead of maven, how can i use gradle.

how can i configure gradle configuration [image]

because in maven there are Working directory and command line, how can i do that in gradle ?
[image]

should i change the port to 8000, tomcat use 8080.
[image]

it connect to 5005
[image]

but localhost is not work
[image]

Comment: If you use port 8080, then keep it. All other steps should be the same for both build tools.

Comment: thanks but i got : 14:06 Error running 'avecTomcat': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8080): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"

Comment: Sorry, debug port should be 5005. Please check these articles: http://kacperbak.github.io/Debugging-a-spring-mvc-web-app-with-the-gradle-tomcat-plugin-and-IntelliJ-IDEA.html, http://www.likeaboss.lt/build-war-with-gradle-and-debug-using-intellij/

Comment: What does "localhost"8080" show?

Answer (score 0):

i just add tomcat plugin and configure it